# Android Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin

```
 mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){ task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Successful login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    var currentUser =mAuth!!.currentUser
                    //save in database
                    if(currentUser!=null) {
                        myRef.child("Users").child(SplitString(currentUser.email.toString())).child("Request").setValue(currentUser.uid)
                    }

                    LoadMain()

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fail login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }
```

I get "developer warning for package 'com.example.package' Failed to post notification on channel 'null' See log for more details"

In the log

```
    DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10932470
Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

I have

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
```

}

in build.gradle

I've been lookin at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels, but I don't know how to work on this

Comment: the code you have posted has nothing to do with notifications.

Answer (score 1):

your version of play services is old. 
use latest google play services in gradle:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    }
```

Comment: i tried adding it but i get compatibility problem with `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'`

Comment: can show the error it shows for compatibility issue? I'm using these two libraries in my project and they are working fine.

Comment: it's not the issue with the play-services version it has to do with another library using lower version, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962984/4428159

Answer (score 0):

For Oreo Copatability you must use channels and group them to run on Oreo (android O) otherwise your notifications will be dropped.
Use this link to Learn more about channels in Android O [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)

medium [link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c)

Read about android O changes [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)