# Error: when I replace compile with implementation in gradle(dependency)

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, javacompiler

I update my Android Studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

But after the update when I build my project it shows **2 warning**:

**1. Replace compile with implementation** (and compile support will be ended at end of 2018)

**2. Replace testCompile with testImplementaion** (and testCompile support will be ended at end of 2018)

So, finally do these changes but after that, it shows **some error**:

[image: error]

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "biz.coolpage.aashish.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

**build.gradle(Project:Abc)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is in your build.gradle

Comment: @Pulkit updated my question with build.gradle

Comment: Can you show what your gradle file was before this as well?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie before this, in dependency section instead of `implementation` `compile` were written that's it.

Comment: How about the gradle file of your library?

Comment: In gradle file of my library, I do the same changes. i.e, replace compile with implementation.

Comment: can you add the second build.gradle also just want to be sure of one thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `api` instead of `implementation` inside your library's gradle. If you have submodules and want to expose the libraries in a transitive manner `api` should be used. `implementation` would import the library for the specific project. Also you might have to add

```
implementation (project(":library")) {
    transitive = true
}
```

For example in your `build.gradle` file of your library module use:

```
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

If nothing works you can try to **invalidate cache and restart**

Comment: I already tried to invalidate the cache and restart but the error still persists.

Comment: did you add `api` instead of `implementation` inside your library's module like `api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"` ?

Comment: Thanks, it works when I replace implementation with api all error vanishes. But I want to known why it suggest to replace with `implementation` instead of `api`.

Comment: as mentioned in the comment the `implementation` is a final import for project level and you cannot have transitive property for that you need to have `api` check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle

Comment: It is better to put this comment link in your answer as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Been there;
just make sure your gradle plugin is up to date and you didn't add or remove anything to the plugins source code and you're good to go